# Implementation is not general enough in async fn

Tags: asynchronous, rust, lifetime

The following code fails to compile:

```rust
use std::marker::PhantomData;

use async_trait::async_trait;

#[async_trait(?Send)]
trait App {
    async fn call_app<'req>(&self, req: &'req str);
}

#[async_trait(?Send)]
trait AppWrapper<'req> {
    async fn wrapped_call(&self, req: &'req str);
}

#[async_trait(?Send)]
trait Handle<'req> {
    async fn handle_call(&self, req: &'req [u8]);
}

#[async_trait(?Send)]
impl<'req, F> Handle<'req> for F
where
    F: Fn(&'req [u8]),
{
    async fn handle_call(&self, req: &'req [u8]) {
        self(req)
    }
}

struct IntoApp<'req, H: Handle<'req>> {
    handle: H,
    _marker: PhantomData<&'req ()>,
}

impl<'req, H: Handle<'req>> IntoApp<'req, H> {
    fn new(handle: H) -> Self {
        Self {
            handle,
            _marker: PhantomData,
        }
    }
}

#[async_trait(?Send)]
impl<'req, H: Handle<'req>> AppWrapper<'req> for IntoApp<'req, H> {
    async fn wrapped_call(&self, req: &'req str) {
        self.handle.handle_call(req.as_bytes()).await;
    }
}

#[async_trait(?Send)]
impl<T> App for T
where
    T: for<'req> AppWrapper<'req>,
{
    async fn call_app<'req>(&self, req: &'req str) {
        self.wrapped_call(req).await
    }
}

fn test(s: &[u8]) {}

fn run() {
    let boxed: Box<dyn App> = Box::new(IntoApp::new(test)); // error
}
```

The error message is:

```
error: implementation of `test::AppWrapper` is not general enough
  --> src/app/test.rs:76:31
   |
76 |     let boxed: Box<dyn App> = Box::new(app);
   |                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ implementation of `test::AppWrapper` is not general enough
   |
   = note: `test::AppWrapper<'0>` would have to be implemented for the type `test::IntoApp<'_, for<'r> fn(&'r [u8]) {test::test}>`, for any lifetime `'0`...
   = note: ...but `test::AppWrapper<'1>` is actually implemented for the type `test::IntoApp<'1, for<'r> fn(&'r [u8]) {test::test}>`, for some specific lifetime `'1`
```

I'm confused about it when I remove `AppWrapper`.

```rust
use async_trait::async_trait;

#[async_trait(?Send)]
trait App {
    async fn call_app<'req>(&self, req: &'req str);
}

#[async_trait(?Send)]
trait AppWrapper<'req> {
    async fn wrapped_call(&self, req: &'req str);
}

#[async_trait(?Send)]
trait Handle<'req> {
    async fn handle_call(&self, req: &'req [u8]);
}

#[async_trait(?Send)]
impl<'req, F> Handle<'req> for F
where
    F: Fn(&'req [u8]),
{
    async fn handle_call(&self, req: &'req [u8]) {
        self(req)
    }
}

#[async_trait(?Send)]
impl<'req, H: Handle<'req>> AppWrapper<'req> for H {
    async fn wrapped_call(&self, req: &'req str) {
        self.handle_call(req.as_bytes()).await;
    }
}

#[async_trait(?Send)]
impl<T> App for T
where
    T: for<'req> AppWrapper<'req>,
{
    async fn call_app<'req>(&self, req: &'req str) {
        self.wrapped_call(req).await;
    }
}

fn test(s: &[u8]) {}

fn run() {
    let boxed: Box<dyn App> = Box::new(test);
}
```

It succeeds to compile, but why? What is the actual problem here?

Answer (score 0):

This is not related to `async`. [This is reproduced even without it](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=233228719b0d45b1db860d374d3fe4c4):

```rust
use std::marker::PhantomData;

trait App {
    fn call_app<'req>(&self, req: &'req str);
}

trait AppWrapper<'req> {
    fn wrapped_call(&self, req: &'req str);
}

trait Handle<'req> {
    fn handle_call(&self, req: &'req [u8]);
}

impl<'req, F> Handle<'req> for F
where
    F: Fn(&'req [u8]),
{
    fn handle_call(&self, req: &'req [u8]) {
        self(req)
    }
}

struct IntoApp<'req, H: Handle<'req>> {
    handle: H,
    _marker: PhantomData<&'req ()>,
}

impl<'req, H: Handle<'req>> IntoApp<'req, H> {
    fn new(handle: H) -> Self {
        Self {
            handle,
            _marker: PhantomData,
        }
    }
}

impl<'req, H: Handle<'req>> AppWrapper<'req> for IntoApp<'req, H> {
    fn wrapped_call(&self, req: &'req str) {
        self.handle.handle_call(req.as_bytes());
    }
}

impl<T> App for T
where
    T: for<'req> AppWrapper<'req>,
{
    fn call_app<'req>(&self, req: &'req str) {
        self.wrapped_call(req)
    }
}

fn test(s: &[u8]) {}

fn run() {
    let boxed: Box<dyn App> = Box::new(IntoApp::new(test)); // error
}
```

The problem is essentially that you're mixing HRTB and normal generic lifetimes. `App` uses HRTB (`where T: for<'req> AppWrapper<'req>`) but `Handle`, `AppWrapper` and `IntoApp` have a generic parameter `'req`. This does not work because you cannot expect `IntoApp` to implement `AppWrapper` for *any* `'req`, only for its own `'req`. It works with only `Handle` somewhat accidentally: because there is no struct in between (`IntoApp`) the compiler can "see through" that the HRTB is actually true (since the `impl` is always applicable we can say that it works for any lifetime). But once you introduce `IntoApp` this is no longer true as `IntoApp` forces one and only one lifetime (because it contains it).

The fix is to either use only lifetime parameters or only HRTB. What is best depends on your goal. For example, using only lifetime parameters:

```rust
trait App<'req> {
    fn call_app(&self, req: &'req str);
}

impl<'req, T> App<'req> for T
where
    T: AppWrapper<'req>,
{
    fn call_app(&self, req: &'req str) {
        self.wrapped_call(req)
    }
}
```